# grep works in shell but not in r.script

Tags: r, subset, grepl, read.csv

When I try to select rows in R by the grep and subset command, it populates correctly when ran in the shell of RStudio line by line; however, when I run the r.script, it just copies the column (variable) names but does not populate.

```
# Reads in yearly data
YearlyData <- read.csv(file="2017.csv", header = FALSE, sep=",")

# Sorts and only include TMAX and TMIN
YearlyDataTMAXMIN <- subset(YearlyData, grepl("TMAX|TMIN", YearlyData$TYPE))
```

Essentially in SQL format, I am trying to do,

```
SELECT * FROM YearlyData WHERE TYPE in ('TMAX, TMIN')
```

in R.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: I think my ordering of my lines was wrong. I moved it toward the bottom of my script and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

A more precise translation from your SQL would be

```
subset(YearlyData, TYPE == "TMAX" | TYPE == "TMIN")
```

or

```
subset(YearlyData, TYPE %in% c("TMAX", "TMIN"))
```

The semantic difference is that grepl will match columns that have "TMAX" or "TMIN" as a substring, e.g. "0123TMAX4567".

Comment: Thanks for the tip!